# How to set specif value in slider ...?

Tags: slider, selenium-webdriver, jquery-ui-slider

I am able to move the slider but not able to set slider on specific value.

```
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 driver.get("");
 WebElement Slider = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='slider-range']/a[1]"));
 Actions moveSlider = new Actions(driver);
 Action action = moveSlider.dragAndDropBy(Slider, 30, 0).build();
 action.perform();
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML that you are trying to manipulate? Also, please remember to highlight your code next time you ask a question.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/slider/ And thanks for Suggestion and editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Found the solution for the above program, by rearranging URl value we can achieve  this.

    URL url = new URL("http://www.myntra.com/women-sarees?nav_id=606&s=tn#!pricerange=2799:9099");  
    String str =url.toString(); 
    int index =  str.indexOf("pricerange");                                                   
    String before = str.substring(index);
    String SubValue = before.substring(E_index); 
    String value1   = SubValue.substring(1,5);      
    String value2   = SubValue.substring(6);    
    String newValue1 = "3000";                                                              
    String newValue2 = "5000";
    String beforeurl = str.substring(0,63); 
    String newUrl = beforeurl+newValue1+":"+newValue2;  System.out.println("New URL -> "+newUrl); driver.get(newUrl);
```

Comment: But, by using the above code, are we really testing the functionality of the slider bar ?

Comment: Actually my Query is not to test the slider but to set the slider at specific values.

Comment: @Hemanth actually i came to the same issue. so what would you suggest to do if the accepted answer is not testing the slider functionality? since i cannot get/set the value of the slider to a specific value see the slider [here](https://pcpartpicker.com/guide/#X=0,172203)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `moveByOffset()` method to move the slider to a particular point.

```
WebElement Slider = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='slider-range']/a[1]"));

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

Action dragAndDrop =

builder.clickAndHold(Slider).moveByOffset(xOffset,yOffset).release().build();

dragAndDrop.perform();
```

Comment: i know how to move slider through offset but if i want to set slider on specific value than...? u can refer a www.Homeshop18.com website for that.